MYSQL UPDATE query not updating
i have a table coin_price and in that table i have two columns, the important column is called coin_price too, i have an UPDATE expression that im executing in my code. after the expression it seems that the coin_price table hasnt changed at all, though no error is left, and no useful information in the results object is left either, after this the code seems to run fine, heres introduce a snippet of my code:
connection.query(mysql_buy_coin_string, [result[0].coin_price + ((8 * req.body.price_paid) / 100) * result[0].coin_price], function(err2, result1, fields1) {
  if (err2)
    res.json({
      error: err2
    });
  else {
    connection.query(mysql_add_coin_to_account_string, [req.body.price_paid, payload.user_id], function(err3, result2, fields2) {
      if (err3)
        res.json({
          error: err3
        });
      else {
        sockets.forEach(function(ws, id) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            reason_for_send: "new coin price",
            coin_price: result[0].coin_price + ((8 * req.body.price_paid) / 100) * result[0].coin_price
          }));
        });
        console.log(result1);
        console.log(result[0].coin_price + ((8 * req.body.price_paid) / 100) * result[0].coin_price);
        res.json({
          operation: "successful"
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
}

and heres the mysql_buy_coin_string:
let mysql_buy_coin_string = `
    update coin_price
    set coin_price = ?;
`;

there really wasnt much that i knew to try, as you can see in the function, ive tried to log some calculations, and they are all correct. the compiler doesnt even find any errors, im really stumped here. id like to thank in advance anyone who could help me.

You're lucky. If your query in mysql_buy_coin_string had worked it would damage all your data. For this column, the specified value would be set in ALL rows of the table. You must add correct WHERE and update only needed row(s).

the table coin_price only consists of 1 value, and it is meant to be that way. i couldnt really think of another way to store that value, so that it wouldnt take up an entire table.

If so then check sql_safe_updates system variable value.

sql_safe_updates is off. it only worked when i changed it directly from the terminal or mysql workbench, but it didnt work in the express js file

If so then there is some inaccuracy in your JS code... from MySQL looking point the query is correct. You may try to enable MySQL General Log temporarily and look what query text is received by MySQL in practice.

i couldnt really find the general log file, i only found the slow-log file, but i logged the result object of this query and on of the rows is this info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',, so it knows theres a row, but decided not to change it??? heres the entire object ResultSetHeader {
fieldCount: 0,
affectedRows: 1,
insertId: 0,
info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
serverStatus: 34,
warningStatus: 0,
changedRows: 0
}

i couldnt really find the general log file https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 means that the value of coin_price is already the value you tried to assign to it, so nothing changed.

im sorry for the late response, the value for coin_price is 1, and console.log(result[0].coin_price + ((8 * req.body.price_paid) / 100) * result[0].coin_price); through my tests, doesnt always return 1. maybe a possible issue is that somehow console.log(result[0].coin_price + ((8 * req.body.price_paid) / 100) * result[0].coin_price); is being rounded down or truncated?

well i just found the problem.... and like basically all programming problems, the problem is cause by very stupid things! in my case, the coin_price column inside coin_price table was an unsigned int datatype! and i had only ever tested that query with  values that would cause the calculations to return values less than 1.5, so thats why it said that 1 column was noticed, but zero were changed!, still, i thank you for bearing with, and helping me, your assistance is appreciated!
